# How to serialize all ArrayList objects created in one method?

Tags: java, serialization, arraylist

I have been struggling to create a serializing method that serializes all my already existing objects. This is what I have done:

my class:

```
public class Test implements Serializable{
    ArrayList<TheOtherClass> obj = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Test test = new Test();
            test.addTest("This", "Is", "Some");
            test.addTest("Text", "As", "Example");
            test.saveAllArrays();
    }
// omitted code down here.
    public void addTest(String some, String random, String text) {
    obj.add(new TheOtherClass(some, random, text));
}
    public void saveTest(Object obj) throws IOException{
                ObjectOutputStream save = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("SaveFile.bin"));
                save.writeObject(obj);
    }

    public void saveAllArrays(){
        for(TheOtherClass all : obj){
            try {
                saveTest(all);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

my object class:

```
    public class TheOtherClass implements Serializable{
            private String some;
            private String random;
            private String savedText;
```

Getter and setter methods are omitted.

Comment: It is something else in the real code, this was just an example, but thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Where is your `addTest()` declaration and implementation? Also, your question needs to explain the problems you have encountered.  Just "struggling with" doesn't tell us much...

Comment: Where is `saveAllArrays()`? And `test test = new test();` won't work since the class is called `Test`. Please just post the actual code you are trying to run, not a random example with problems all over. Also, you should tell us what the exact issue is - error? exception? wrong output?

Comment: sorry about that I just fixed it. Hope it is fine now. I can unfortunately not put my actual code up otherwise my work will be flagged for plagiarism when I turn it in. The problem I was encountering is that I do not know why it is not serializing.

Comment: Okay, it's not serializing, but what is it doing instead? Is it throwing an exception? Is the output to the file not what you expected and if so, what is the output, generally?

Comment: It is running without issues and simply just not adding anything to the "SaveFile.bin" however "SaveFile.bin" is created the only problem is that the file itself is empty.

Comment: Nothing that you're showing is incorrect, other than the semantics of it. (e.g. are `addTest` and `saveAllArrays` part of `TheOtherClass`??)  Only other thing might be you might want to thing about passing a `File` to `FileOutputStream` instead of a `String`

Comment: how do I add a file rather than a string to the FileOutputStream? Do you mean like add the directory of the file?

Comment: @BhargavModi `Object` is *not* a reserved word in Java.

Comment: No like this:  `new ObjectOuputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(pathToFileAsString)));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a complete example. Hopefully it will get you moving.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Test implements Serializable {

    private static final String FILE = "SaveFile.bin";

    private List<Item> itemList = new ArrayList<>();

    public class Item implements Serializable {
        private String first;
        private String second;
        private String last;
        public Item(String first, String second, String last) {
            this.first = first;
            this.second = second;
            this.last = last;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return first + ", " + second + ", " + last;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Test test = new Test();
        if(args.length > 0) {
            try {
                test.loadItemList();
                System.out.println("loaded");
                test.printList();
            } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            test.addItem("1", "2", "done");
            test.addItem("Text", "As", "Example");
            try {
                test.saveItemList();
                System.out.println("saved");
                test.printList();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    private void printList() {
        itemList.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private void addItem(String first, String second, String last) {
        itemList.add(new Item(first, second, last));
    }

    private void loadItemList() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(FILE);
        ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
        itemList = (List<Item>) objectInputStream.readObject();
    }

    private void saveItemList() throws IOException {
        OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(FILE);
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(itemList);
    }
}
```

Comment: This helped me, thanks to this my code is working, thank you.

Comment: Nice. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

At present you're creating a new file per serialized object, so you lose all but the last one. There is no need to serialize multiple objects at all, or iterate over the array list. Just save it directly, and deserialize it directly too.

Comment: do you mean in the addTest() method?

Comment: You aren't iterating over anything in the `addTest()` method. I don't know why you ask. I refer to the place where you *are* iterating: the `saveAllArrays()` method, and in whatever code does the deserialization.